# Meaning of "@" operator in R language?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I came across the following and I haven't figured out the purpose of the "@" operator.  What's the meaning there?  I didn't make heads/tails of the R manual language.

```
library(lattice)
library(sp)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

p <- xyplot(copper ~ cadmium, data = meuse@data, col = "grey", pch = 20, cex = 2)
```

R manuals says

> Usage
>   object@name
>   object@name <- value
>
> Extract or replace the contents of a slot in a object with a formal (S4) class structure.
>   These operators support the formal classes of package methods, and are enabled only when package methods is loaded (as per default). See slot for further details, in particular for the differences between slot() and the @ operator.
>
> It is checked that object is an S4 object (see isS4), and it is an error to attempt to use @ on any other object. (There is an exception for name .Data for internal use only.) The replacement operator checks that the slot already exists on the object (which it should if the object is really from the class it claims to be).

I checked the structure of "meuse" and found no references to a slot named "data".

Comment: check out Hadley's fantastic resource on R objects http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s4

Comment: Why would you expect a slot named "data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meuse` is an S4 object

```
isS4(meuse)
[1] TRUE
```

If you take the structure of of `meuse` (`str_meuse`) you'll see some fields are denoted with your `@` operator, including one called `data`.  These slots can be accessed with `@` similar to how you might see other slots in other objects accessed using the `$` operator.  So `meuse@data` gives you the `data` portion of the `meuse` object.

`str(meuse)`

```
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 155 obs. of  12 variables:
  .. ..$ cadmium: num [1:155] 11.7 8.6 6.5 2.6 2.8 3 3.2 2.8 2.4 1.6 ...
  .. ..$ copper : num [1:155] 85 81 68 81 48 61 31 29 37 24 ...
  .. ..$ lead   : num [1:155] 299 277 199 116 117 137 132 150 133 80 ...
  .. ..$ zinc   : num [1:155] 1022 1141 640 257 269 ...
  .. ..$ elev   : num [1:155] 7.91 6.98 7.8 7.66 7.48 ...
  .. ..$ dist   : num [1:155] 0.00136 0.01222 0.10303 0.19009 0.27709 ...
  .. ..$ om     : num [1:155] 13.6 14 13 8 8.7 7.8 9.2 9.5 10.6 6.3 ...
  .. ..$ ffreq  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ soil   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
  .. ..$ lime   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ landuse: Factor w/ 15 levels "Aa","Ab","Ag",..: 4 4 4 11 4 11 4 2 2 15 ...
  .. ..$ dist.m : num [1:155] 50 30 150 270 380 470 240 120 240 420 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
  ..@ coords     : num [1:155, 1:2] 181072 181025 181165 181298 18130
```

See how that subsetting is working?

```
str(meuse@data)
'data.frame':   155 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ cadmium: num  11.7 8.6 6.5 2.6 2.8 3 3.2 2.8 2.4 1.6 ...
 $ copper : num  85 81 68 81 48 61 31 29 37 24 ...
 $ lead   : num  299 277 199 116 117 137 132 150 133 80 ...
 $ zinc   : num  1022 1141 640 257 269 ...
 $ elev   : num  7.91 6.98 7.8 7.66 7.48 ...
 $ dist   : num  0.00136 0.01222 0.10303 0.19009 0.27709 ...
 $ om     : num  13.6 14 13 8 8.7 7.8 9.2 9.5 10.6 6.3 ...
 $ ffreq  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ soil   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ lime   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ landuse: Factor w/ 15 levels "Aa","Ab","Ag",..: 4 4 4 11 4 11 4 2 2 15 ...
 $ dist.m : num  50 30 150 270 380 470 240 120 240 420 ...
```

Comment: Strange how I didn't get that output when I executed str() on meuse.  With that, I wouldn't have bothered asking the question :)  Wickham also gives a useful explanation...  "(@ is equivalent to $, and slot() to [[.)"

Comment: @user2438292 check again. Start a new session. And then try `str(meuse)` *Before* you use `coordinates(meuse)<- ~x+y` and *After* you have used it.... Also try `isS4` in both cases and see....